# Excel How To Count Dynamic values for Duplicates

Tags: excel

I seem to be having issues finding a solution,

I want to count duplications in a row, the row has 100 columns. I Just want to count many how duplications across the row.

For example,

```
1,2,3,1,4,9,2,9,1,4
```

I just want to see how many times the same set of numbers show up.

```
1 = 3
2 = 2 
3 = 0
4 = 2
9 = 2
```

For example, `3 + 2 + 0 + 2 + 2 = 9`

This row has 9 duplications. ie the same value is being displayed more than once. However the value is dynamic.

Comment: If the above data is in B5:L5 = {1,2,3,1,4,9,2,9,1,4} then `SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(B5:L5,B5:L5)>1)*(COUNTIF(B5:L5,B5:L5)>1))` = 9

Comment: @StandardCitizen You have 3 answers. Please, to guide others who may come to this thread with the same question, please mark the solution you used as "Selected". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The VBA function below is a UDF, meaning it's like a normal Excel worksheet function but doing designed to do precisely what you want. Install it in a standard code module.

```
Function CountDuplicates(Rng As Range) As Integer
' set a Reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"

    Dim Fun As Integer                      ' function return value
    Dim Uniques As Scripting.Dictionary     ' list of occurrences
    Dim Arr As Variant                      ' array of all values
    Dim C As Long

    Set Uniques = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Arr = Rng.Value
    With Uniques
        For C = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
            If Not IsEmpty(Arr(1, C)) Then
                If .Exists(Arr(1, C)) Then
                    .Item(Arr(1, C)) = .Item(Arr(1, C)) + 1
                Else
                    .Add Arr(1, C), 0
                End If
            End If
        Next C

        For C = 0 To .Count - 1
            Fun = Fun + .Items(C)
        Next C
    End With

    CountDuplicates = Fun
End Function
```

A standard code module is one that you must add to your project. Its default name will be like *Module1* but you can change it to anything you like (wrong syntax names will be rejected). Call the function from the worksheet by entering its call in any cell, for example.

```
= CountDuplicates(A2:DD2)
```

This function will return the number of all duplicates counted in the defined range, excluding unique values. Look at the code. When an item is found for the first time a value of 0 is recorded against it. Thereafter, each time it is found again 1 is added to the number of recurrences already found. In the end all values will be added up to return the total count. This method ensures that all first occurrences will be counted as 0 (meaning not counted). Only repeats are included in the returned total.

As with other Excel functions, the result will appear in the cell containing the formula. You can copy that formula down as you do with any other, meaning the original above must be in row 2. If you paste it elsewhere consider the use of absolute addressing to define the action range.

Comment: Just tried it and it returns 5, which is the number of duplicates in addition to the first appearance of each number which is a correct interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have O365 with the `UNIQUE` function, you can use:

```
=COUNT(A1:J1)-COUNT(UNIQUE(A1:J1,TRUE,TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: This is the total count minus the number of unique values that occur only once, so it's a correct interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
=COUNT(A1:J1)-SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(A1:J1,A1:J1)=1))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(A1:J1,A1:J1)>1))
```